# How to capture SharePoint events from the UI?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I would need to capture events that users do on a SharePoint site (or at least Central Administration) - kind of "click on Site Settings" -> " click on Master pages gallery" etc...

I guess that's quite easy as a Sharepoint site is in the end a simple web site - but what would be the best approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MOSS Usage Tools from Codeplex is a solution that process SharePoint usage logs into BI.
friendly repository. This solution can monitor, audit, and gain valuable insight from the content and activity information within MOSS 
http://usage.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can also use the auditing support built into MOSS. MOSS provide support for auditing user access to pages, content, and documents, and include auditable events such as "Opening or downloading documents, Viewing items in list or item properties, Editing items,Checking out,Checking in,Moving or copying items to another location in the site,Deleting or restoring items."
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA100997261033.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on the SharePoint STS usage logs to provide a list of pages that were visited by a given login.

The raw logs provide a list of every url visited.
I used [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2005/05/29/409614.aspx) to create an app to import what I wanted to a database.